# Converting DateTime to AM/PM Time

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a windows form and I was wondering how to change a DateTime to an am/pm time. Currently, I have a TextBox that enters a time. When I enter something like 4:00 pm, it converts it to 16:00, which is correct. However, when I went to display it, it shows the 16:00. I'm not sure what I should do in my SQL select statement to show 4:00 pm. Right now, my SQL statement is just calling the default value from the database (*). Wondering what I could do with that to get what I need.

Comment: You need to perform the stringformatting for this purpose. Don't need to worry with how the data is stored and retrieved from database

Comment: Use Convert.ToDateTime(strDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt") in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm for a lot of the formatting rules and examples.